# How to execute text from a flask form as if it were html

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I would like to take text from a flask form and execute it in an HTML script.
Here is a minimal example of what I mean:

```
// PYTHON

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextAreaField, SubmitField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "a_secret"

class Form(FlaskForm):
    html = TextAreaField("HTML to be excecuted: ")
    submit = SubmitField("Submit code")

code = ""

@app.route("/make_code", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def make_code():
    form = Form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        global code
        code = form.html.data
        return redirect(url_for("see_code"))
    return render_template("make_code.html", form=form)

@app.route("/see_code")
def see_code():
    return render_template("see_code.html", code=code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

// make_code.html

<form method="POST">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  {{ form.csrf_token }}

  {{ form.html.label }}
  {{ form.html() }}

  {{ form.submit() }}
</form>

// see_code.html

{{ code }}
```

However, when I submit `<strong>Hello</strong>`, flask changes it to be `&lt;strong&gt;Hello&lt;/strong&gt;gt;`
Is there any way to stop this?